# __attribute__ ((constructor)) in shared libraries and zend php extension

Tags: php, c++, attributes

hi i have a c++ shared library which is used by nodejs and php extension at the same time.
im facing a weird issue regarding the shared variables in the c++ library.
i have in my c++ library

```
vector<string> support_list;

void _generateSupporList() {
    //.....
    support_list.push_back("test1");
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) lib_init(void) {
     // when this code is called the php extension will always see 1 element in the array 
    _generateSupporList();
}

myClass {
    public: 
        appendSupportedList();
}
myClass::appendSupportedList(string item){
    cout << support_list.size();
    // when i append the same array i'll have 2 elements temporarily.. but when i do another call(new user request from browser) i'll see one element only "test1"..
    support_list.push_back(item);
}
```

now let assume we have user request -> http://example.com/test.php?append=val
in test.php Im calling the php extension which in turn calls the c++ api.
so in test.php :

```
  $class = new myClass();//defined in the php extension
  $class->appendSupportedList($_GET['append']); //this line will append support_list with "val"..
```

another user has requested the same page -> http://example.com/test.php?append=val2
the same code will be executed and we will have a new item added to support_list.
when user calls test.php for 10 times i always get the same size for support_list..
Im expecting from the above code to have 
request 1 -> support_list.size() = 1
request 2 -> support_list.size() = 2
request 3 -> support_list.size() = 3

but i always have support_list.size() = 1 // which is the one added by "lib_init"

Comment: Totally confusing. What is your question?

Comment: Try compiling with all warnings enabled: `-Wall -Wextra`. Then handle them.

Comment: @Deduplicator i have rephrased the question